# How to get a List of objects having a particular property using Predicate

Tags: java, list, java-8, predicate

I'm trying to find all the employees whose salary is greater than 50k using a lambda expression.

But I'm not able to access the `getSalary()` method.

```
ArrayList<emp> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new emp("Ronaldo",1,90000,"UTD"));
list.add(new emp("Rooney",2,40000,"HOME"));

Predicate<ArrayList<emp>> p3 = (s) -> s.getSalary() > 50000;

System.out.println(p3.test(list));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this!**

```java
List<Employees> empGreaterThan = list.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getSalary() > 5000).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Make sure `getSalary()` is defined in your Employee class or you are using `Lombok` or similar plugin to generate Getter/setters !

**Alternatively, if you want to define your own predicate, you can do like this**

```java
Predicate<Employee> myPredicate= emp -> emp.getSalary() > 5000;
List<Employee> newList=  list.stream().filter(myPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to find the value using only existing Predicate Functional Interface and without using streams.

Comment: The "test()" method of predicate will only check if the argument you are passing to test() falls in the Predicate boundary!  for e.g. predicate.test(emp1)  , if emp1 has salary > 5000, then it will return true ! I suggest you read Java docs on it

Answer (score 2):

[`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) is a *functional interface* built-in the JDK representing a `boolean`-value function.

It's method `test()` returns `true` or `false` it's meant to verify whether an object passed as an argument matches the condition.

***Sidenote:** get familiar with [Java Naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), `emp` - ins't a good name for a class. And also have a look at this question [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)*

Your definition and usage of the *predicate* is incorrect:

```
(s) -> s.getSalary() > 50000
```

Argument `s` is of type `List<Employee>`, therefore you can't apply `getSalary()` on it.

And your expectation that `p3.test(list)` will give a *list* as a result is also wrong. Predicate is meant to produce a `boolean` value and nothing more.

Instead, you need to iterate over the *list of employee* and apply the *predicate* on each *element* in the list during the iteration process.

The most convenient way approach is to create a stream (as shown in the answer by *@Harsh*). You can also do it using a plain `for` loop.

```
public static Predicate<Employee> salaryGraterThen(int salary) {
    return emp -> emp.getSalary() > salary;
}
```

```
Predicate<Employee> salaryGraterThen50K = salaryGraterThen(50_000);
        
List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();
        
for (Employee emp: list) {
    if (salaryGraterThen50K.test(emp)) result.add(emp);
}
```

It can also be done using `removeIf()` method of the `Collection` interface, that expects a `Predicate` as an argument and will remove every element for which the given *predicate* will be evaluated to `true`.

For that, we need to make a copy of the initial list (to keep it intact):

```
List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
result.removeIf(emp -> emp.getSalary() <= 50_000);
```